# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') but id doesn´t, anomaly detection

Tags: python, error-handling, nan, anomaly-detection

My data has the following aspect:

```
    h=df1.iloc[[2]]

    output:
    action_query               10424567
    Day                               
    2017-09-20                       0
    2017-09-21                       0
    2017-09-22                       0
    2017-09-23                       2
    2017-09-24                       0
    2017-09-25                       0
    2017-09-26                       1
    2017-09-27                       0
```

I want to apply an anomaly detection (elliptic envelope) for each action_query based on the it's comportment through the days. But when i run the exact data above, it returns the following error:

```
    from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope
    outliersfin=[]
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        Elliptic= EllipticEnvelope(contamination=0.0010)
        h=df1.iloc[[i]]
        h1=h.transpose()
        Elliptic.fit(h1)
        outliers= Elliptic.predict(h1)
        outlierfin.append(outliers)

   ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

All the values are in the format int, so that is not the problem.

```
    h.dtype()
    Day          int64
    action_query int64
```

Comment: Please specify what function/code is applied to the data. And what's an ouptup of `df.dtypes`, where `df` is your data?